# Default mapping for specific destination

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

Today I am using Entity framework together with Automapper to map to viewmodels. More or less every class has 1 or more reference to the User-table/User-class (My own, not in Identity-namespace).

This is getting slow due to the fact that is is mapping the user from database today. 1 per row, or all together depending on lazy loading or not.

Is it possible to somehow set a default behavior for Automapper so when destination is UserViewModel, is it will resolve using an in-memory-list instead of database?

I can of course map this with ResolveUsing on my map configuration, but I rather not do this per type since this is a large project.

Comment: Can you share some code about how you are mapping user from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Custom Type Converter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) will likely work for you here. They specify mappings between two types at a global scope. So you can define the conversion once within your AutoMapper configuration and it will be applied to any mapping of those types.

Here's an example of what one may look like:

```
public class UserViewModelConverter : ITypeConverter<object, UserViewModel>
{
    private static readonly UserViewModel _instance = new UserViewModel
    {
        Foo = "StaticValue"
    };

    public UserViewModel Convert(object source, UserViewModel destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Setting the source as `object` will make this converter apply to every mapping where the source is an object and the destination is `UserViewModel`. I'm just returning a static instance here, however you could inject other dependencies into this class if you want to access the data from elsewhere (implementations of `ITypeConverter` will be resolved Transiently).

---

And here's a full example of this working:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IMapper mapper = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<object, UserViewModel>().ConvertUsing<UserViewModelConverter>();
        }).CreateMapper();

        UserViewModel viewModelFromOne = mapper.Map<UserViewModel>(new SourceOne { Foo = "One" });
        UserViewModel viewModelFromTwo = mapper.Map<UserViewModel>(new SourceTwo { Foo = "Two" });

        Console.WriteLine($"Foo from One {viewModelFromOne.Foo}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Foo from Two {viewModelFromTwo.Foo}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class UserViewModelConverter : ITypeConverter<object, UserViewModel>
{
    private static readonly UserViewModel _instance = new UserViewModel
    {
        Foo = "StaticValue"
    };

    public UserViewModel Convert(object source, UserViewModel destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _instance;
    }
}

public class SourceOne
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class SourceTwo
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public UserViewModel()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instantiating UserViewModel...");
    }

    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

You can see that a single `UserViewModel` instance is created and returned when mapping from any source type.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for.